# ResteasyClient API not working for test cases

Tags: java, resteasy

I am using Resteasy + Spring MVC + Hibernate. I have successfully developed the code, but when I updated the Resteasy dependency ti its latest version I see that most of the API's are deprecated, so I changed by following test case to

```
static final String ROOT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/";

@Test
    public void testCustomerById() throws Exception{
        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(ROOT_URL+"customerservice/getcustomer/1");
        request.accept("application/json");

        //Obtaining the client response
        ClientResponse response = request.get(Customer.class);

        if(response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode() != 200){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : "+ response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode());
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        Customer customer = (Customer) response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("STATUS     : "+response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Name       : "+customer.getName());
        System.out.println("Age        : "+customer.getAge());
        System.out.println("CustomerId : "+customer.getCustomerId());
    }
```

**to**

```
@Test
    public void testCustomerByIdNewAPI() throws Exception{
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(ROOT_URL));
        ICustomerService proxy = target.proxy(ICustomerService.class);

        CustomerType customerType = proxy.getCustomerInfo(1);
        System.out.println("Name       : "+customerType.getName());
        System.out.println("Age        : "+customerType.getAge());
        System.out.println("CustomerId : "+customerType.getCustomerId());
    }
```

But when I run the above test case I see the following error

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:181)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getCustomerInfo(Unknown Source)
    at test.resteasy.series.spring.mvc.hibernate.service.CustomerTest.testCustomerByIdNewAPI(CustomerTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**The logs from tomcat server:**

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:112) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerMapping.getInvoker(ResteasyHandlerMapping.java:109) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerMapping.getHandler(ResteasyHandlerMapping.java:85) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1123) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:934) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
2016-12-24 18:20:19 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc-hibernate-resteasy'
2016-12-24 18:20:19 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
2016-12-24 18:22:33 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc-hibernate-resteasy' processing GET request for [/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1]
2016-12-24 18:22:33 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1
2016-12-24 18:22:33 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1]
2016-12-24 18:22:33 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR o.j.r.s.ResteasyHandlerMapping - Resource Not Found: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerMapping.getInvoker(ResteasyHandlerMapping.java:109) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerMapping.getHandler(ResteasyHandlerMapping.java:85) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1123) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:934) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) [catalina.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.73]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
2016-12-24 18:22:33 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/resteasy/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc-hibernate-resteasy'
2016-12-24 18:22:33 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Looks like your rest endpoints aren't being mapped. Post the output from your spring startup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. I see the issue too. The test cases should be developed like below:

```
final String path = "http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/";
ICustomerService proxy = null;

    @Before
    public void beforeClass(){
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(path));
        proxy = target.proxy(ICustomerService.class);
    }

@Test
    public void testCustomerByIdNewAPI() throws Exception{  
        CustomerType customerType = proxy.getCustomerInfo(1);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Name       : "+customerType.getName());
        System.out.println("Age        : "+customerType.getAge());
        System.out.println("CustomerId : "+customerType.getCustomerId());
    }
```